# Is a postgres trigger C function blocking?

Tags: c, postgresql, triggers

As the title suggests, my short question is : When using a dynamically loaded C function with a postgres trigger, is that a blocking or non-blocking call?

Background:
I need to generate some XML following an insert/update/delete on my database. The two options I've considered are:

1. Create some event table which is written to using during an I/U/D operation and have a daemon poll for these events and generate XML
2. Create a C function to generate this XML as part of a trigger in postgres.

Using option 2 would provide real-time updates but my concern is that there will be some overhead in generating the XML message and transmitting it etc, so inserting 100rows would take a lot longer due to creating an xml between each operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with "blocking"? If you mean whether the trigger "time" will add to the insert/update/delete time, then yes it is "blocking".

Comment: By blocking I mean when the function is called, no other database operations will occur until it has finished. Eg if 2 rows are inserted the process is; insert row, call function <some time passes> function returns, insert second row...

Comment: Of course other database operations can occur. And you can have more than one insert running at the same time. You have to make sure your C-function is thread safe

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Other DB operations can occur concurrent in _other_ sessions/transactions, but not in the same session the trigger is running in *unless* they're invoked by the trigger. Just for clarity.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Also, the C function must be re-entrant as well as thread safe, as a trigger may directly or indirectly invoke its self again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it "blocks". The SQL that causes the trigger to run does not complete until the trigger is done.

See more info in the [docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtrigger.html).

Answer (score 4):

Triggers, whether implemented in C or any other language, are synchronous. One trigger executes at a time, and no further non-trigger statement may run until all triggers have run. In PostgreSQL, triggers execute in alphabetical order.

Note that unless they take locks, triggers do *not* block statements in *other* transactions. The same trigger can be running at three different points of execution in three different transactions, while a fourth transaction runs a later trigger on the same table and a fifth is just beginning an `INSERT`.

Thus, a trigger blocks later statements on the same transaction, but not statements on other transactions.

BTW, PostgreSQL doesn't offer asynchronous triggers; they can't return control so more statements execute while continuing to run. All triggers are blocking and synchronous. Asynchronous trigger equivalents are kind-of possible via `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY` or queueing mechanisms like `PgQ`. If you're worried about speed, have your trigger `NOTIFY` a `LISTEN`ing daemon that does the generation asynchronously.